# Python basic types do not count inheritance

Tags: python, inheritance, types

Python basic types do not count inheritance as I expected. For example:

```
class MyUnicode(unicode):
    pass

mu = MyUnicode('xxx')

>>> type(mu)
<class '__main__.MyUnicode'> # ok

>>> type(mu + 'x')
<type 'unicode'> # why not <class '__main__.MyUnicode'> ?

>>> type(mu.strip())
<type 'unicode'> # why not <class '__main__.MyUnicode'> ?
```

Strings are immutable, then those two methods must return new objects. But why developers hardcoded the `unicode` return type inside those methods instead of using sub-class?
Does it prevent some potential drawbacks, I'm not aware of?

Comment: I remember this has been asked before, but I cannot find the reference at the moment.  Python's behaviour used to be rather inconsistent in the past -- strings and integers would return the base class, while e.g. sets would return your derived class.  If I remember correctly, current Python 3 always returns the built-in base types and not the derived types.  If you search for the commits in CPython that changed this behaviour you'll probably find the explanation why they did this.

Answer (score 2):

Personally I would like to see how can you implement `unicode` to work the way you want, without relying on some implementation details of the subclass.

If you'll try (it's a pseudocode for obvious reasons):

```
def __add__(self, other):
    return type(self)(concatenate(self.string, other.string))
```

You are forcing the class to have a single-arg constructor. why? In addition, you have `mu + u'x'` and `u'x' + mu` being of different types, and it also guaranteed to be less efficient.

There is no reason to do additional work only for some unknown unlikely subclass to behave in some specific way. I don't think `unicode` is designed to be subclassed; If you do subclass it, and want a different behavior than you base class, go ahead and override the relevant methods yourself.

Comment: Why not to expect that subclass has the same signature? I'm sure than you use `cls` in your code, not harcoded names. By hardcoding names you make a bigger assumption (about your code future using) than by relying on signature.

Answer (score 1):

You didn't overrride `.strip` and `__add__`, which by default still return unicode objects and not instances of you class. Here is the [source](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/70274d53c1dd/Objects/unicodeobject.c#l6954) for the strip functionality (2.7.3). As for why the developers decided to return a Py_UNICODE object from a unicode method instead of checking for a subclass first and returning that? I think the idea here is you are given just enough to do it yourself.

Comment: This is exactly what OP said. But why those methods are like that? You didn't explain

Answer (score 0):

Because Python tends to favor simplicity, it is usually not aware of subclasses when dealing with built-in types.

On the main implementation (written in C), it is easier to cast something to `Py_UCS4` or `PyListObject` or other type defined in C than to fetch dynamically a type and call the constructor (that might not be compatible with the super class constructor and crash).

The rule of thumb is to replace all the methods you need if you want to fully replace a built-in class, but I advise against.

Many times, it is simpler to just make it an attribute of a class and add methods as you need:

```
class MyUnicode(object):
    def __init__(self, u):
        self.u = unicode(u)
```

Comment: I don't believe that reason is simplicity. There are definitely hidden roots for such behavior. I just can't see it. You are correct that I could wrap unicode object instead of subclassing and hook __getattribute__ etc. I just have read sentence somewhere in the docs that subclassing base classes is *good idea*... Not so good, as it turned out.

Answer (score 0):

After multiple comments from OP, I've decided to rewrite my answer from scratch.

**Possible workaround:**

```
class MyUnicodeMetaClass(type):

    autocast_methods = ('__add__', '__radd__', 'format')

    def __init__(cls, name, bases, attrs):   
        super(MyUnicodeMetaClass, cls).__init__(name, bases, attrs)
        for method_name in MyUnicodeMetaClass.autocast_methods:
            try:
                setattr(cls, method_name, cls.autocast_creator(method_name))
            except AttributeError:
                if method_name.startswith('__r'):
                    setattr(cls, method_name, cls.autocast_reverse(method_name))
                else:
                    raise

    def autocast_creator(cls, method_name):
        method = unicode().__getattribute__(method_name)
        def autocast_method(self, *args, **kwargs):
            method = unicode(self).__getattribute__(method_name)
            return cls(method(*args, **kwargs))
        return autocast_method

    def autocast_reverse(cls, method_name):
        method_name = method_name.replace('__r', '__', 1)
        def autocast_method(self, *args, **kwargs):
            method = unicode(args[0]).__getattribute__(method_name)
            return cls(method(self, *args[1:], **kwargs))
        return autocast_method


class MyUnicode(unicode):
    __metaclass__ = MyUnicodeMetaClass

a = MyUnicode(u'aaa {0}')
print a, type(a)
# aaa {0} <class '__main__.MyUnicode'>
b = a + u'bbb'
print b, type(b)
# aaa {0}bbb <class '__main__.MyUnicode'>
c = u'ddd' + a
print c, type(c)
# cccaaa {0} <class '__main__.MyUnicode'>
d = a.format(115)
print d, type(d)
# aaa 115 <class '__main__.MyUnicode'>
```

*It might require extending but the base skeleton is ready.*
What is happening here?
1. `Metaclass` is used to alter creation of `MyUnicode` class.
2. Simple `autocast_creator` is used to populate `MyUnicode` class with methods that should return `MyUnicode` instead of `unicode`.
3. A **little** more sophisticated `autocast_reverse` is used to provide reverse methods as well (like `__radd__` which is needed when first operand is `unicode` and second one is `MyUnicode`)
*This way, you don't have to manually override all the methods - just list them in `autocast_methods` tuple.*

**Background information:**

***Inheritance:***
Object Oriented Programming is intended to reflect real word as well as possible.
Inheritance is no exception here.

In real world a group of elephants **is always** a group of animals. No doubts here.
But a group of animals **might be** a group of elephants but it can also be a group of various animals and there can even be no elephant in this group.
This is because any group of elephants is a special kind of group of animals.
So it can be reflected in computer programme by defining `ElephantGroup` as a **subclass** of `AnimalGroup`.
How can `ElephantGroup` extend `AnimalGroup`? For example by defining new field `ivory_weight` and new method `toot()`.
Consider such a simple operation `ElephantGroup() + AnimalGroup()`.
What is the class of expected result? `AnimalGroup` - no magic here and rats, dolphins etc. won't become elephants. Rats and dolphins don't provide ivory and they can't toot, so forcing them to do so is not an expected behavior.

Let's get back to `MyUnicode` and `unicode`.
Machines aren't intelligent in the meaning presented in Matrix or Terminator.
The Python interpreter doesn't understand what is the purpose of `MyUnicode`.
Consider a class extending `unicode` or `str` (doesn't really matter here) that is named `EmailAddress` and is intended to hold e-mail address. No surprise :)
And we have a code snippet now:

```
a = EmailAddress(u'example@example.com')
b = u'/!\n'
c = a + b
d = b + a
```

Still expecting `c` and `d` to be instances of `EmailAddress`? (Or `MyUnicode`?)
If you have answered **yes** then please tell me:
1. What if `EmailAddress.__init__(...)` contains well crafted logic checking if an argument is likely to be a valid e-mail address?  And it raises exception if it isn't...
2. How can interpreter be aware that it can safely initialize `MyUnicode` instance with **any** `unicode` instance without executing `__init__`? Please also remember this is Python and `__init__` can even be changed dynamically at runtime.
*Remember - we can always cast instance to any of it's ancestors. The reverse operation can't be done implicitly. It would be a mess if the interpreter would implicitly cast `object` instances to `objects` subclasses.*
The `strip()` method follows the same rules - `unicode` characters are removed from the original and a reference to new `unicode` instance is returned (unless exact same `unicode` exists - in this case the reference to existing one is returned).

***Referring to instance class:***

In one of your comments you said `cls` refers to the class of instance that started the execution chain...
`cls` is a naming convention used in `metaclasses`, `classmethods` and in `__new__()` method to indicate that we **don't have an instance** - we only have a class.
In fact we can't access instance in any of these cases - `__new__()` however should return new instance in most cases.

I guess you were thinking of `identifier.__class__` attribute. It has nothing to do with execution chain either. It points to the actual class of instance referred by `identifier`.
Why do you expect methods of `unicode` and `str` to use it to create subclasses?
Casting something implicitly to it's subclass is not an expected behavior - I know, one of the operands in your code is `MyUnicode` but the other one is `unicode` - even in `strip()`, the default argument is a `unicode` containg whitespace characters.

***Some unicode implementation details:***

Python `unicode` and `string` types are immutable and **unique** (explanation is coming).
Immutable means that any modyfying operation on them returns *other* instance of `unicode` or `string` respectively.
**Other instance** would mean **new instance** but as I said these types are **unique**.
What it means? See the code:

```
a = u'aaa'
b = u'aaa'
```

What happened here?
There was a **new instance** of `unicode` created to initialize `a`.
The `unicode` object to initialize `b` was found so no new instance was created.
Instead a reference counter to `unicode` object holding `u'aaa'` was incremented.

Now when we know it, consider this code:

```
a = u'aaa'
b = MyUnicode(u'aa')
c = b + u'a'
```

What exactly is stored in `c` variable? A reference to `unicode` object - the same object which is referenced by `a`.
Why changing `c` won't affect `a`?  Because `unicode` is **immutable** and underlying object remains unchanged.
If the next line would be `c = c + u'b'`, then `c` would get reference to new/other instance and object referenced by `a` would have it's reference counter decreased.

**Conclusions:**

The Python `unicode` and `str` classes are consistent and predictive.
There are some types that are hard to derive from, due to optimization, special purposes or implementation details.
`unicode` and `str` are rather not intended to be subclassed altough it can be achieved for instance with `metaclass` as in my snippet.

As always I'm looking for any constructive criticism and comments.

Good luck!

Comment: I definitely can override all required methods (so-o-o many) but when developers decide to add one more I will be forced to change my old code... Not a friendly behavior at all. I expected from Python that it will use derived class whenever possible like we do in own code. Keeping initializator's call signature(especially of a base-type class!) out of modifications is usual practice to rely on.

Comment: @IvanKleshnin, where do you see `initializator's call signature modification` in my code? I said that you are free to modify `MyUnicode` `__init__` to accept more arguments than `unicode`. I didn't said you have to. I think you misunderstand inheritance. Abstract example: `AppleJuice` inherits from `FruitJuice`. Would you really like the interpreter to assume that `AppleJuice + FruitJuice` means more `AppleJuice`? NO! Interpreter can't assume that `base class` can always be safely casted to `descendant class`.

Comment: I think you are wrong. AppleJuice & FruitJuice always mean AppleJuice.

Comment: Thats why we use `cls` variable instead of class name.

Comment: You are surprising me... FruitJuice can be OrangeJuice for example. Still thinking that AppleJuice + FruitJuice is always AppleJuice? Interpreter can't figure out what kind of juice FruitJuice is unless explicitly said. All new style classes inherit from _object_ - this doesn't mean any object can be casted to any of it's descendants.

Comment: By using `cls` you just say that: don't bother, use those one which started chain of calls. Lets stop here, please :)